# How to test the content of bbl files with l3build?

Tags: l3build

I am maintaining a set of BibTeX style (bst) files and I want to test the contents of `bbl` files with `l3build`. I've tried the following methods:

1. An undocumented macro `\SHOWFILE` can print the `bbl` file to log file. However, the contents are normalized before written into the `tlg` file: dates like "`2019-01-03`" are replaced with "`....-..-..`" and "`^^M`" is appended to each line, which is a little messy to read.
2. I redefined the `runtest` function in the `build.lua` script to write directly the `bbl` file into `tlg` file but it had no effect.

How can I test the original contents of `bbl` file without normalizing it.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean about `^^M`: both `diff` and `fc` have no issues with files created using `l3build`. We don't have support at present for testing `.bbl` files: the aim of `l3build` is first to deal with TeX testing. Probably proper support for alternative tests needs a bit of thought.